# Azure AD authentication with Asp.net core without App registrations in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I have been trying to do Azure AD authentication with ASP.Net Core application where I want to achieve this without doing the App Registrations, Reply URL settings in Azure.

The Reason being, I want our users from other domains to download our application from azure Marketplace and start logging into the application with AAD without doing the App Registrations step - Is it Possible ?

If not possible, Is there any programmatic approach to create App Registrations, Reply URL and give necessary permissions so as to simplify the process and to enhance user experience

Any Sample documentation/link/solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: What you have sounds like a multi-tenant app. You can register an app in your directory, mark it as multi-tenant, and then any organization can start using the app with their own directory. A service principal gets created automatically once the first user agrees to its permission requirements.

Comment: With multi-tenant app, the moment i try to access with other directory user, i get the following exception "AADSTS65005: The app needs access to a service ("https://xyz.domain.com/b4ad7232-62e0-4ec7-9d68-b3a479bd9847") that your organization "abc.onmicrosoft.com" has not subscribed to or enabled. Contact your IT Admin to review the configuration of your service subscriptions."

Comment: That means the app requires a permission to some API of yours? You can get around this problem by making your app a known client application of the API app by editing the API app's manifest. There you need to update property like this: `knownClientApplications: ["your-app-client-id"]`. Put your app's client id in the array. This will allow the other tenant to consent to both apps at the same time.

Comment: Still, No Luck..It throws the same exception